# How one can create a nice looking figure like this example in Latex?

Tags: graphics, tikz-cd

How to draw a nice-looking table like this example in Latex.

I can draw this diagram in Google Slides and then export that in Latex.

However, the figure does not look as neat like this example which I found in a paper.

Can anyone please give me any pointers?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a start for you!

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily,>=latex,line width=.8pt] 
\def\a{3.5}
\def\b{1.2}
\path[nodes={draw,minimum height=5mm,minimum width=12mm}]
(0,0) node (P) {PRED}
++(\a,0) node (E1) {EXPR}
++(0,-\b) node (E1t) {=}
+(-.2*\a,-\b) node (E1t1) {a}       
+(.2*\a,-\b) node (E1t2) {63}       
(E1)++(\a,0) node (E2) {EXPR}       
;

\draw[densely dotted,->,green!70!black] (P)--(E1) node[above,midway]{True};
\draw[densely dotted,->,green!70!black,shorten >=2mm] (P)--+(0,.8*\b)-|(E2) node[above,pos=.12]{False};
\draw[dash dot,->,blue] (P.south) to[bend right] node[below,midway]{C\_true} (E1.south);
\draw[densely dotted,->,green!70!black] (E1)--(E2);
\draw[dash dot,->,blue] (E1.north) to[bend left] node[below,midway]{D\_a} (E2.north);
\draw[->] (E1)--(E1t);
\draw[->] (E1t)--(E1t1);
\draw[->] (E1t)--(E1t2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```